# Access displayName attribute from the model in MVC View

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

If my model have

```
[DisplayName("First Name")]
public string firstName { get; set; }
```

Then I can print it in the View with LabelFor

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.acc_first)
```

It will then render as

```
<label for="firstName">First Name</label>
```

- But how can I "raw" read the property (FirstName) attributes in the View? 
  If for example, I want to send the value to a function on the View page

Comment: You should accept one of the answers below.

Answer (score 59):

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.acc_first)
```

Answer (score 13):

To access the attributes you'll need a custom `Html` helper. Since the attributes aren't really part of the property or model you need to go in a round about way to access them.

```
public static IHtmlString DisplayName<TModel, TValue>(
                             this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
                             Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) {
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TValue>(expression, html.ViewData);

    return new HtmlString(metadata.DisplayName);
}
```

For additional attributes that aren't part of the DataAnnotations you can do the following:

Create a custom attribute

```
public class TooltipAttribute : Attribute, IMetadataAware {
    public TooltipAttribute(string tooltip) {
        this.Tooltip = tooltip;
    }

    public string Tooltip { get; set; }

    public void OnMetadataCreated(ModelMetadata metadata) {
        metadata.AdditionalValues["Tooltip"] = this.Tooltip;
    }
}
```

The magic happens in the OnMetadataCreated implementation. Here we can populate the AdditionalValues with anything we need for our particular Attribute. In this case we’re adding a Tooltip key. Your name should be unique as other attributes or providers may add their own keys with the same name It is important to remember that attributes are not always read in the same order. So your tooltip attribute may be called first, last or somewhere in the middle. This is an important distinction as it may cause undesired effects.

Then create a custom Attribute helper

```
public static IHtmlString TooltipFor<TModel, TValue>(
                             this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
                             Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression) {
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression<TModel, TValue>(expression, html.ViewData);
    if (metadata.AdditionalValues.ContainsKey("Tooltip"))
        return new HtmlString((string)metadata.AdditionalValues["Tooltip"]);

    return new HtmlString("");
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use your example as @Html.TooltipFor(model=>model.Name) and keep getting error: The type argument for method cannot be inferred from usage, try specifying the arguments.

Answer (score 6):

You can access the value of the attribute `Display(Name="...")` in 4 steps:

```
var type = typeof(YourNamespace.Models.YourModelName);
var memInfo = type.GetMember("firstName"); // your member
var attributes = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute), false);
var displayname = ((System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute)attributes[0]).Name;
```

Then `displayname` will have the value `First Name` in your context.

Answer (score 5):

Building on Darren Oster's answer:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.acc_first)
```

Here's a link to the documentation for this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor(v=vs.118).aspx

You could use this in your view code like this:

```
@{ 
    var foo = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.acc_first);

    // call function
    DoStuff(foo);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you should simply use

```
[Display(Name = "First Name")]


 public string name{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<label asp-for="firstName">First Name</label>
```

you must change for to asp-for

Answer (score 0):

[Display(Name ="First Name")]

Comment: This answer was already given right?

Answer (score -3):

```
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.acc_first)
```

should work for you. If not, try just

```
@Model.acc_first
```

Either one should work fine.

Comment: The question is asking about getting the property's Display Name (from the DisplayNameAttribute), not the property's value.

Answer (score -4):

`@(This.Model.acc_first)`

Should work

so in javascript you can use it like

```
function callme(val)
{
   //some ajax call with 
   @(This.Model.acc_first)
}
```

Comment: The question is asking about getting the property's Display Name (from the DisplayNameAttribute), not the property's value.