# Provide data annotation for placeholder attr for textbox in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html, viewmodel

Is there a way to have a data annotation for what should be in `placeholder` attr on a textbox in an MVC view?

Example:

**In my ViewModel.cs, something like:**

```
[Placeholder="First name"]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

**In my view:**

```
@this.Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
```

If that could render this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="First name" ... />
```

Is this possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try

```
@this.Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new{placeholder="First name"})
```

Ah, not in the model.

You can define your own custome attribute http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aspnetue/archive/2010/02/24/attributes-and-asp-net-mvc.aspx.  I think you will need a custom html helper to generate the html.

Comment: this is great! do you know which attribute I would need to inherit from? the example in your link inherits from `ActionFilterAttribute`

Comment: the example has a list of attribute classes, pick the one that is closest to what you want to do. Or use inherit from System.Attribute for a clean(er) start.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this has been asked a long, long time ago but the `Display` attribute with the `Prompt` argument is probably what you want here.

```
    [Display(Prompt = "Enter the country (default US)")]
    public string Country { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, but you could write your own custom helper and attribute to do it. http://www.aspnetwiki.com/page:creating-custom-html-helpers

Comment: thanks for the link! unfortunately, I don't see any examples where I can have `[Placeholder="First name"]` above the property in my view model.  Instead, there are examples for `this.Html.TextboxFor(m => m.FirstName, "Placeholder text here")`, which would defeat the purpose because I want this hard-coded text to be with the view model, not in the view.

Comment: I know, you would need to roll your own helper and attribute. Here, BuildStarted's answer shows how he created a custom attribute, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7418664/access-displayname-attribute-from-the-model-in-mvc-view. You custom helper could then read your custom attribute.